# How can i trigger a function in JS file from gmail addon button?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-workspace, google-apps-marketplace, gmail-addons

I have js library which has some inbuilt functionalities required for our application. Now i want to import my js library and its css files in Gmail addon. After that i want bind a function to that button id so that whenever the button is clicked function in my library executes.

How can i do that? Please see sample code

As per the sample code **myLib.js** has function **myFunc()** which takes component id and url to be opened. So i created button and binding **myFunc** to it. How can i do the same thing using ***googlescript for gmail addon***.

Thanks in Advance

```
   <head>
      <script src="https://*/app.bundle.js"> </script>
      <script src="https://*/app.bundle.css"> </script>
      <script src="https://*/myLib.js"> </script>
   </head>
   <body>
     <button id="app">Clickhere</button>
     <script>
        myFunc('#app',URL);
     </script>
   </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Gmail Add-ons (if what you are talking about is indeed a Gmail Add-on) use [Card-based interface](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/card-service) and cannot be created with custom `html` and 'css'. Once built such an interface, create a function that executes your library's function:

```
/**
 * Triggers library function;
 * @param {Object} e event object;
 */
function myTrigger(e) {
  //access event object's params;
  var parameters = e.parameters; 
  var id  = parameters.id;
  var url = parameters.url;      

  //you can reference lib functions by prepending its name;
  myLibrary.myFunc();
}
```

Import your library by clicking on the project's command bar button **Resources**, then choose **Libraries** and import your project (assuming your library can be converted into an apps script project, if not, there is not much that you can do). Besides, Google [discourages from](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries) using libraries in Add-ons.

You can, of course, load the external non-GAS library via `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` by using `eval()` (ctrq have a [great tutorial](https://ctrlq.org/code/20380-load-external-javascript-with-eval) on how to do that), but you are probably aware that `eval()` brings [security risks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Do_not_ever_use_eval!) to your app.

Then, configure an `Action` on a target Ui element (most likely a `TextButton`):

```
//...created a TextButton and wrote it into a var tb;

//create parameters object (aquire id and url however you want)
var parameters = {
 id  : '', 
 url : '' 
};

//reference Enum loadIndicator (only NONE or SPINNER currently);
var loadIndicator = CardService.LoadIndicator.SPINNER;

//create Action to set;
var action = CardService.newAction();
    action.setFunctionName('myTrigger'); //reference trigger function;
    action.setLoadIndicator(loadIndicator); //set a load indicator, if not invoked equals NONE;
    action.setParameters(parameters) //every key in this object are strings!;

//set Action to TextButton;
tb.setOnClickAction(action);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I implemented as you said. But when i call Mylibrary.myFunc(). it is giving error like myFunc() was not found but it was loaded into myLibrary variable.  I think the error is because we are loading the library file as.     `var appCode = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://*/app.bundle.js').getContentText();
  var style = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://*/app.bundle.css').getContentText();
  var myLibrary = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://*/myLib.js').getContentText();` as this. it was actually loading in string format. so i am unable to call myFunc in it. How can i load it as object ?

Comment: if i do eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://*/app.bundle.js').getContentText()); i am getting error like.  **Missing name after . operator**

Comment: @vinaynarayana - everything is OK with your loading procedure and eval() - please, make sure your library does not contain anything that apps script cannot parse (a big chunk of ES6) - e.g. classes, arrow functions (if not using typescript), etc. It parses a sample library absolutely fine.